# Shared connection to server closed

Tags: ssh, ansible

When I run this:

```
$ ansible -i s1, s1 -m raw -a 'echo test' -u root -k
```

I get:

```
s1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
test
Shared connection to s1 closed.
```

But this way:

```
$ ansible -i s1, s1 -m command -a 'echo test' -u root -k
```

I don't get "Shared connection to s1 closed." part:

```
s1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
test
```

Why is that?

P.S. Above is a simplified way to reproduce the issue. What I'm facing is that when running playbook I get this extra line which is in the way.

**UPD** The line clearly coming from `ssh`. And if I run `raw` command with `-vvvv`, I get:

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
<s1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<s1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d13 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto
  -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10
  -o ControlPath=/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt s1
  'echo test'
s1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
test
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/yuri/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-s1-22-root" does not exist
<...a lot of output from ssh...>
```

But with `command`, it's just:

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
Using module file
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/commands/command.py
<s1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<s1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d13 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto
  -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10
  -o ControlPath=/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r s1
  '/bin/sh -c '"'"'(
    umask 77
    && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737 `"
    && echo ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737 `"
  ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<s1> PUT /tmp/tmpes82wL TO
  /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737/command.py
<s1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d13 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -vvv -C
  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root
  -o ConnectTimeout=10
  -o ControlPath=/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[s1]'
<s1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<s1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d13 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto
  -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10
  -o ControlPath=/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r s1
  '/bin/sh -c '"'"'
    chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737/command.py
    && sleep 0'"'"''
<s1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<s1> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d13 ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto
  -o ControlPersist=60s -o User=root -o ConnectTimeout=10
  -o ControlPath=/home/yuri/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt s1
  '/bin/sh -c '"'"'
    /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737/command.py;
    rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1488989540.6-73006073289737/" > /dev/null 2>&1
    && sleep 0'"'"''
s1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
test
```

Where is all `ssh` output gone?

Comment: Try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shared connection to s1 closed.

This message is an error message from ssh client.

With `raw: echo test` Ansible executes `ssh <many parameters> s1 'echo test'` and you get *stdout/stderr from **ssh** command*. This way message about shared connection pops up in your task result.

With `command: echo test` Ansible copy python-wrapper (`command.py`) and execute this wrapper, which in turn spawns `echo test` and capture *stdout/stderr from **echo** commmand*. Then `command.py` prints `echo`'s result as JSON-object with `stdout`/`stderr`/`rc` keys. The ssh error message still occurs, but you don't see it (it is filtered by Ansible), because Ansible get task result from JSON-object key's and not from ssh plain stdout/stderr/rc.

> Where is all ssh output gone?

This is related due to the same difference in handling raw/command. To see detailed ssh output set `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1` environment variable.

If you want to hide this error message, you can use `ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o LogLevel=QUIET'` inventory variable. But I'm not sure if this can give some other unexpected results.

Comment: With `ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o LogLevel=QUIET'` I might miss some important messages from `ssh`, might I? Concerning "because task's result is captured by python-wrapper inside ssh session" part, I'm more then sure the result is captured not by `~/.ansible/tmp/.../command.py` running on remote host (if that's what you meant), but by the part running locally on control node. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `I might miss some important messages`, yes there is a possibility. `command.py` captures `echo`'s output and send it (actually print to stdout) to control node in a form of JSON object with `stdout`/`stderr`/`rc` keys, so Ansible relies on this object instead of raw ssh output. Check log with `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1`, it gives a clear picture of what's going on.

Comment: My conjecture confirmed. With `raw` module, `ansible` simply executes [one command](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.5.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/raw.py#L41) over ssh, taking as stdout what was send to stdout, and similarly with stderr...

Comment: With `command` module it takes more than that. It [executes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.5.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py#L33) a [bunch of commands](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.5.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L666), discarding output of all but stdout of [the last one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.5.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L679), filtering out [non-json lines](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.1.5.0-0.2.rc2/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L724).

Comment: Yes, this is true. And you may see this in verbose logs in your question...

Comment: So, ideally it'd be great to be able to add `2>/dev/null` to `ssh` command. But that doesn't seem to be possible. So rather then changing `LogLevel` to `QUIET`, which suppresses [`ssh` fatal errors](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203346/29867) for all commands in playbook, the better option seems to be to remove this particular line from the output, if need be.

Comment: Oh, and correct please this sentence: "The ssh error message still occurs, but you don't see it, because task's result is captured by python-wrapper inside ssh session." Error message is filtered out by `ansible` running locally (on a control node). It occurs after `python` wrapper finished running.